# ASP MVC Razor Render Partial Not Finding The Correct Route Details

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to run `@{ Html.RenderAction("List", "Template"); }` in my parent view.

My parent view maps to controller = EmailTemplateHost Action = Index

Which I have registered using:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "TemplateIndex",
            "Template",
            new { controller = "EmailTemplateHost", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Template/List should map to controller = EmailTemplateList action = List

Which I have registered using:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "TemplateList",
            "Template/List",
            new { controller = "EmailTemplateList", action = "List" }
        );
```

All of the routes are in the RouteTable. However upon rendering my Index page when it hits the RenderAction it hits the Windsor Controller Factory asking for the controller name of Template and not EmailTemplateList. It seems as if it isn't going through the routing engine. If I look in the request context the route data values is showing Template and List in the dictionary but it is not showing the mapping I require to find the correct controller.

Oh yea if I use `@{ Html.RenderAction("List", "EmailTemplateList"); }`

It works!

Any thoughts?

Thanks Jonathan.

Answer (score 0):

Put the second route TemplateList above the TemplateIndex route in your global.asax.